# select query with if function with multiple choices

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
SELECT UserName,
       IF(status=1, 'open', status) status,
       IF(status=2, 'closed', status) status,
       c_name
FROM ADMIN a
JOIN admin_course_ ad ON a.adminID=ad.fk_user_id
JOIN admin_courses ac ON ac.c_id=ad.fk_c_id
```

my requirement is i got status=1,2,3,4 from tables so instead of `1 2 3 4` i want to return `open closed pending defer`so tried

```
IF(status=1, 'open', status) status,IF(status=2, 'closed', status) status
```

but i didn't get expected values.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CASE statement. For example:

```
SELECT c_name,
       UserName,
       (CASE status
            WHEN 1 THEN 'open'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'closed'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'pending'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'defer'
            ELSE "undefined"
        END) AS status_title
FROM admin a
JOIN admin_course_ ad ON a.adminID=ad.fk_user_id
JOIN admin_courses ac ON ac.c_id=ad.fk_c_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a status types table with the code, name and a description column. Once you have this you will not need any condition on your query, as youll get name by a inner join between tables.

```
select a.UserName, ..., s.name
from admin a 
inner join statuses s on s.statusCode = a.status
join admin_course_ -- rest of your joins and query
...
```

You can also achieve what you want with a CASE clause of mysql (look this code example took from mysql documentation https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp):

```
SELECT OrderID, Quantity,
CASE
    WHEN Quantity > 30 THEN "The quantity is greater than 30"
    WHEN Quantity = 30 THEN "The quantity is 30"
    ELSE "The quantity is something else"
END
FROM OrderDetails;
```

Hope this helps